# Divide number into equal parts and populate into array

Tags: javascript

Given numbers `number`, `n` and `interval` I'm trying to divide them into equal intervals and pre-populate them into an array.

The rule is if we add up these equal intervals it needs to sum up to the original number.

---

### Examples:

> Input:

```
number = 8, n = 2, interval = 4
```

> Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

---

> Input:

```
number = 56, n = 8, interval = 7
```

> Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

---

Input 
number = 9, number = 2, interval = 3

Output

```
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

---

**The problem is the array which I am creating is not equally divided as per the value of the interval.**

Here's the code which I am trying,

```js
var dividend = 9,
  divisor = 2,
  interval = 3;

var res = (function(number, n, interval) {
  values = [];

  while (number && n && interval) {
    if (number % 2 == 0)
      a = Math.floor(number / n);
    else
      a = Math.ceil(number / n);

    n--;
    number -= a;
    interval--;

    values.push(a);
  }
  return values;
})(dividend, divisor, interval);



console.log(res);
```

Comment: So `number` is the sum of all the numbers and `interval` is how many items will be created. Not quite sure what n stands for

Comment: `n` stands for the divisor for which to divide by

Comment: updated variable names @visibleman

Comment: In 1 and 2: n*interval=number but not in 3

Comment: @KunalMukherjee So why should the output of `number = 9, number = 2, interval = 3` be `4,4,1` and not `3,3,3`?

Comment: @nickzoum because `dividend = 9, divisor = 2`, so dividing `9 / 2` will result in `4, 4, 1`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee so what do you need `interval` for, then?

Comment: @TanjaBayer because n and interval were even numbers in those cases

Comment: @nickzoum to decide the length of the resultant array,

Comment: @nickzoum so what should be the output of `number = 9, number = 2, interval = 2` and `number = 9, number = 2, interval = 4`?

Comment: for the first one it should be `[5, 4]` and second one `[2, 2, 2, 1]`

Comment: How do you expect number three to be equally devided? The values can only be equally  devided if it is possible to devide number by n without anything left

Comment: None of those 2 answers make any sense using your own explanation

Comment: [2,2,2,1]=7 Not 9

Comment: What if `interval` > `number` ?

Comment: Also, what should be the output of `9, 7, 3` ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee We still need a few clarifications, you can find our queries in the 'debate' under my answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a solution for three parts, where the

- **sum is equal to the product of value and length,**

  then distribute the value over the length of the result array
- **sum is smaller to the product of value and length,**

  then calculate the greater value `left` and distribute this value over the value as count and for the rest take another value `right`.
- **sum is greater to the product of value and length,**

  here take the value as greatest value to distribute and calculate the count for the left side and the smaler value for the `right` side to distribute.

```js
function getParts(sum, n, length) {
    var left, right;
    if (n * length === sum) return Array.from({ length }, _ => n);
    if (n * length < sum) {
        left = Math.floor(sum / n);
    } else {
        left = n;
        n = Math.floor(sum / left);
    }
    right = (sum - left * n) / (length - n);
    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i < n ? left : right);
}

console.log(getParts(8, 2, 4).join(' '));  // 2 2 2 2
console.log(getParts(56, 8, 7).join(' ')); // 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
console.log(getParts(9, 2, 3).join(' '));  // 4 4 1
console.log(getParts(10, 2, 3).join(' ')); // 5 5 0
console.log(getParts(9, 4, 3).join(' '));  // 4 4 1
console.log(getParts(8, 5, 4).join(' '));  // 5 1 1 1
```

For nearly same distribution of a sum with values, who are close, you could get the following.

```js
function getParts(sum, length) {
    var left = Math.ceil(sum / length),
        right = Math.floor(sum / length),
        first = (sum - right * length) / right;

    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i < first ? left : right);
}

console.log(getParts(8, 5).join(' ')); // 2 2 2 1 1
console.log(getParts(8, 4).join(' ')); // 2 2 2 2
console.log(getParts(8, 3).join(' ')); // 3 2 2
console.log(getParts(9, 3).join(' ')); // 3 3 3
```

Comment: I don't really understand? The question says that there are three input parameters, `number`, `n` and `interval`, but you only use two?

Comment: @ChatterOne, thanks, please see edit. i think it's a special case, if the wanted lenght and the wanted value does not yield the sum, then `n` is the parts count with the greates numbers.

Comment: I think OP should specify the expected behaviour when `interval > (number - n)`, e.g  . `9, 7, 3`, because with that as input your solution gives `1, 1, 1`. But, unless OP specifies what it should be, there's no way of fixing it properly.

Comment: Also, this has the same problem as @nick zoum's answer: with input `9, 4, 3`, I think you should get `4, 4, 1`, but instead here you get `2, 2, 2`

Answer (score 1):

**STEPS:**

1. Find compound (I don't know what to call it) using `Math.ceil(number / (n * interval))` to know how many times to multiply the `n` for the maximum number in each `interval`.
2. Calculate `max_n` from `n * compound`, which is the highest number in each `interval`.
3. Iterate for the number of `interval`.
4. In each iteration,

   - if you `max_n` is higher than or equal to current `number` then push `max_n` and minus `number` by `max_n`.
   - else push the rest (`number`)

```js
var res = (function(number, n, interval) {
  let values = [];
  let compound = Math.ceil(number / (n * interval))
  let max_n = n * compound
  while (interval--) {
    if (number >= max_n) {
      values.push(max_n)
      number -= max_n
    }
    else {
      values.push(number)
    }
  }
  return values;
});

console.log(res(8, 2, 4));
console.log(res(56, 8, 7));
console.log(res(9, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question these two conditions need to be met before filling the array `fill * (interval - 1) <= number`, `fill * interval >= number`, where `fill` starts as `number / n`. Based on that, I made the algorithm you can find below.

```
function populate(number, n, interval) {
  var fill = Math.floor(number / n);
  if (fill * interval < number) fill = Math.ceil(number / interval);
  else if (fill * (interval - 1) > number) fill = Math.ceil(number / (number % interval ? interval - 1 : interval));
  var array = new Array(interval);
  array.fill(fill);
  array[interval - 1] = number - ((interval - 1) * fill);
  return array;
}
```

If you want IE support, change [array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to a for loop like this one:
`for(var index = 0; index < interval - 1; index++) array[index] = fill;`

I also made a snippet, so you can test multiple values

```js
function populate(number, n, interval) {
  var fill = Math.floor(number / n);
  if (fill * interval < number) fill = Math.ceil(number / interval);
  else if (fill * (interval - 1) > number) fill = Math.ceil(number / (number % interval ? interval - 1 : interval));
  var array = new Array(interval);
  array.fill(fill);
  array[interval - 1] = number - ((interval - 1) * fill);
  return array;
}

document.querySelector("#calc").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var number = document.querySelector("#number").value - 0,
    n = document.querySelector("#n").value - 0,
    interval = document.querySelector("#interval").value - 0;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(populate(number, n, interval)));
});
```

```html
<label for="number">Number</label>
<input id="number" type="number" name="number" value="9" />
<label for="n">n</label>
<input id="n" type="number" name="n" value="2" />
<label for="interval">interval</label>
<input id="interval" type="number" name="interval" value="3" />
<input id="calc" type="submit" value="calculate" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this give `[3, 3, 3]` instead of `[4, 4, 1]` ?

Comment: @ChatterOne was still working on it, fixed it now i think

Comment: @nickzoum what is `div` in the function populate?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee `fill` was previously named `div`, thought i had changed all the references. I fixed it now

Comment: With input `9, 4, 3`, I'd expect `4, 4, 1`, but instead the result is `3, 3, 3`

Comment: @ChatterOne Why would you expect that input? `9 / 4 = 2`, that many `2`s won't fit so the n variable gets ignored, right?

Comment: @nickzoum Why not? There's no constraint specified, it follows the rules in the questions and the output is still distributed evenly, having the sum of the elements equal to the number. Why would you not expect it?

Comment: @ChatterOne where does the 4 come from though? Is it because `number = 8, n = 2, interval = 4`, outputs `2,2,2,2`? Because the `2` there comes from `number/interval` and not from `n`

Comment: @nickzoum I have a bit of difficulty understanding what you mean. I was talking about `number = 9, n = 4, interval = 3`, do you think there's some specific reason why that is invalid input? If it's not, it should give the correct result. If it is, it should be handled by returning something specific.

Comment: @ChatterOne I never said it is invalid input. I am just asking how 4 is calculated in `4, 4, 1`, since `9/4 = 2.25` and `9/3 = 3`

Comment: @ChatterOne I think you got confused from the first example in the question with `number = 8, n = 2, interval = 4`. I also got confused by it at the start until OP clarified that `n(2)` is used to divide the `number(8)` and fill the array with the result of the division and not itself. In that case the array is filled with 2s because `8/4 = 2`

Comment: Ok, I clearly don't properly understand the question then

Comment: @ChatterOne please read the comments between myself and OP on the question, I could be wrong but I think the problem here is that pretty much everyone got mislead by the first two examples and just assumed that the array is filled with `n`

Comment: @ChatterOne now that you've read the comments what do you think is the correct output for `9,4,3`?

Comment: @nickzoum I don't think that the array should be filled with `n` because I agree that `9, 2, 3` should give `4, 4, 1`. My point is that if you want to evenly distribute the number, then you should divide it as evenly as possible using `n` as the divisor, and put in the last spot whatever remains. That's why I still think that `9, 4, 3` should give `4, 4, 1`, just like `29, 7, 3` should give `14, 14, 1`, but your code outputs `10, 10, 9`. I think you're just not considering `n` properly. OP should probably clarify

Comment: @ChatterOne Isn't `10,10,9` more even than `14,14,1`? how do you calculate 14? The only way i can think of that makes some sense is `(29 - 1)/2`. But that sets the last element as 1 before any other calculation has been carried out. From what I can understand from the question, the last element should be calculated last based on all the other elements. But yes we do need to wait for further clarification.

Comment: @nickzoum If the only purpose was to evenly distribute the number you'd need only two parameters, the number and the interval. Instead you also have `n`

Comment: @ChatterOne how do you use the `7` in `29, 7, 3`?

Comment: @nickzoum There are as many evenly distributed multiples of `n` as possible, which in this case is 7. You could have `28, 1, 0`, but `14, 14, 1` is more evenly distributed. With `9, 4, 3` you could have `8, 1, 0`, but `4, 4, 1,` is more evenly distributed. With `65, 10, 4`, you'd have `20, 20, 20, 5`.

Comment: @ChatterOne Oh ok, I just assumed that that variable gets ignored in that case. Though, neither of these two approaches is mentioned or hinted in the question. We still need to wait for OP to explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

@KunalMukherjee First of all, you have to decide which is the real rule, but just one rule for all cases.
You said that n stands for divisor, so in case 3 you have 9/2 = 4.5 ~ 4, and the array(3) fits [4, 4, 1]. But this same rule in case 1, 8/2 = 4, and the array(4) fits [4, 4, 0, 0] and not [2, 2, 2, 2]. So, n not stand for divisor, or, the result for case 1 is wrong.